# How to curl service like in the docs for kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am following this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

but I am expecting to be able to curl some localhost:8080 or something like that.

What the the exact curl command and port that is expect FROM THE HOST. Not on the cluster, not on a node, but FROM THE HOST.

I am running in microk8s.

This is the file I have applied, copied from the docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          secretName: nginxsecret
      - name: configmap-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginxconfigmap
      containers:
      - name: nginxhttps
        image: bprashanth/nginxhttps:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
          name: secret-volume
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: configmap-volume
```

This is the output of the `k get deployment my-nginx -o yaml` command:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-nginx","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"run":"my-nginx"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"run":"my-nginx"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"bprashanth/nginxhttps:1.0","name":"nginxhttps","ports":[{"containerPort":443},{"containerPort":80}],"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/etc/nginx/ssl","name":"secret-volume"},{"mountPath":"/etc/nginx/conf.d","name":"configmap-volume"}]}],"volumes":[{"name":"secret-volume","secret":{"secretName":"nginxsecret"}},{"configMap":{"name":"nginxconfigmap"},"name":"configmap-volume"}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-31T19:25:30Z"
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:rollingUpdate:
            .: {}
            f:maxSurge: {}
            f:maxUnavailable: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:run: {}
          f:spec:
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"nginxhttps"}:
                .: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/etc/nginx/conf.d"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/etc/nginx/ssl"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"configmap-volume"}:
                .: {}
                f:configMap:
                  .: {}
                  f:defaultMode: {}
                  f:name: {}
                f:name: {}
              k:{"name":"secret-volume"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:secret:
                  .: {}
                  f:defaultMode: {}
                  f:secretName: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-31T19:25:30Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-31T19:25:31Z"
  name: my-nginx
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "764711"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/my-nginx
  uid: 77061fd6-8a88-4e0d-891b-6dcc5df2c95e
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: bprashanth/nginxhttps:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginxhttps
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
          name: secret-volume
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: configmap-volume
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: nginxsecret
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: nginxconfigmap
        name: configmap-volume
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-01-31T19:25:31Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-01-31T19:25:31Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-01-31T19:25:30Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2021-01-31T19:25:31Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "my-nginx-5b6fb7fb46" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

There is also this default.conf as in the docs

```
 cat default.conf
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the `kubectl get deployment  < deployment-name> -o yaml` output?

Comment: it's better if you add the yaml that you have tried?

Comment: @H.R.Emon I've updated with the details. This is why I often complain about these kind of docs ... they should *always* just have a make file with a README.md there is not point in all of this copy pasta as it does not really help you learn. You learn when you try your own project.

Answer (score 1):

try `curl -k 127.0.0.1:80` or `curl -k localhost:80`. actually the `8080` port is for the `service` but when you try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` they don't connect through `service` so the `port` need to be the `container`'s port which is `80`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a proxy to your pod with:

```
kubectl port-forward [name of your pod] [port-on-the-host]:[pod-port]
```

Then you can access it via your host:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:pod-port
```

in your case:
$ curl 127.0.0.1:80

In your case `80` is a `targetPort`which is the port on the  *pod*  that the request gets sent to

But it is solution without using [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Read more: [kubernetes-port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod).